# PFQuery Mixing nearGeoPoint with Bool

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

When I run the following

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EventsTable"];
    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

    //  Only active items
    [query whereKey:@"active" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    //  Query by distance from current location
    [query whereKey:@"geoLocation" nearGeoPoint:currentLocation];
    // Only download objects that match the appropriate key
    [query whereKey:@"keyedItems" containedIn:keysArray];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *eventArray, NSError *error) {
```

It goes into an infinite loop with no error messages. But If I drop the nearGeoPoint it works fine, or if I keep the nearGeoPoint but drop the active it also works. But dropping the containedIn and keeping the nearGeoPoint and the active also fail the same way. I have also tried rearranging the order but no luck.

Any suggestions?

At first I wasn't able to find an error message so I assumed that it was stuck in the block, but alas here it is

Error: Error Domain=Parse Code=1 "{"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}" UserInfo={error={"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}, NSLocalizedDescription={"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}, code=1} {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "{\"code\":1,\"message\":\"Internal server error.\"}";
    code = 1;
    error = "{\"code\":1,\"message\":\"Internal server error.\"}";
}

This sounds like a parse server error to me - Is that correct?

Comment: are you sure it's an infinite loop?  that sounds unlikely.  do you log the NSError in the completion handler?

Comment: about 2/3 the way down here (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/621) somebody indicates that they fixed a geospatial query (that seems to fail like yours) by creating an index in mongo https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-a-2d-index/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the table was so large it was unable to handle the query. The fix was just as mentioned above - to create an index. In this case I was able to turn on automatic indexing in the MongoDB. That solved the problem.